# mysql lowest score formula by number of vulnerabilities and severity levels

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to find a formula that would identify the least vulnerable teams based on number of vulnerabilities found and severity levels.

| address | critical | medium | low |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| siteA | 3 | 1 | 13 |
| siteB | 1 | 2 | 5 |
| siteC | 0 | 5 | 12 |
| siteD | 5 | 2 | 10 |
| siteE | 2 | 0 | 8 |

```
    SELECT address, COUNT(*) AS total FROM scanner
    GROUP BY address ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 1000
    where admin = "xxx" and severity = "critical"
```

The MySQL syntax above was used to get the most vulnerable teams.

Now, I want to opposite, I would like to display the LEAST vulnerable teams.

1. Teams having 0 Critical and 0 Medium will be at the top.
2. Teams having the lowest Medium and Low will be next
3. etc...

Any starting pointer would be great and appreciated

Comment: Teams = Site (Address)

Comment: your code above is wrong and should give you an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to SUM the occurrences and sort by it ascending

```
SELECT 
    address,
    SUM(severity = 'critical') AS critical,
    SUM(severity = 'medium') AS medium,
    SUM(severity = 'low') AS low
FROM
    scanner
GROUP BY address
ORDER BY critical ASC , medium ASC , low ASC;
```

Still your could can not work.

It should be

```
SELECT 
    address, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM
    scanner
WHERE
    admin = 'xxx' AND severity = 'critical'
GROUP BY address
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 1000
```